# How to show rounded alert/information window (Similar to alert when changing sound in os x)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to show some nice (un-annoying) alert in my app (OS X) on some few events.
Is there something similar to OS X default alert when changing sound (or when you dim/brighten your screen)?

[image: Sound changes OS X]
I've been using `NSAlert`, but only for warnings.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in. You'll need to create a borderless window, set `opaque` to false, set `backgroundColor` to `[NSColor clearColor]`, set `hasShadow` to false. Set the `level` to something in front of most other windows, probably `kCGOverlayWindowLevel`.

For its content view, you'd use a custom view which draws the rounded rect shape. On 10.10 and later, you'd want to use vibrancy to get the frosted appearance in your screenshot. On earlier versions of the OS, you would draw a semi-transparent gray or black color.

You'd either draw the other content in that same custom view or, perhaps better, add subviews to do it.

You would fade it in and out by setting the window's `alphaValue`. You'd set it to 0, order the window to the front, then animate it to 1. Reverse that to fade it out.

The system bezels — that's what they're called in some obscure place in Apple's docs that I can't find at the moment — don't interfere with each other. Only one is drawn at a time. Unfortunately, there's no way for yours to participate in that system.

Comment: Couldn't ask for more comprehensive answer! I'll go with creating custom view (border, alpha, animations...) and I'll add custom subviews to it. As of second part. It's no problem, if two or more will interfere (which won't happen in normal circumstances). Anyway, thanks again.